# Perform specific action on button in Bootstrap modal (Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I created a modal which displays information specific to their id entries and placed the Approve and Reject button as below.

[Screenshot of modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYfbM.jpg)

When a user click on "Accept" or "Reject", it needs to pass id related to the viewed entries so the user can perform the requested action, whether to accept or reject the entries (default status is 'pending').

**vendor.blade.php**

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <span class="pull-left">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('approve') }}">
      @method('PUT')
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Approve</button>
     </form>
  </span>
  <span class="pull-right">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('reject') }}">
      @method('PUT')
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Reject</button>
    </form>
  </span>
</div>
```

In **VendorController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $vendors = DB::select('select company_name, roc_no, created_at from mides_vendors');

    $vendor_id = Vendor::where('status', 'Pending');

    return view('panel.vendor', ['vendors' => $vendors]);
}
```

**ApprovedVendorController.php**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Vendor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ApproveVendorController extends Controller
{
    public function approve(Request $request, $id)
    {
     DB::insert('insert into mides_users(name, email, password) select name,roc_no,password from mides_vendors where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);
     DB::update('update mides_vendors set status = :status where id = :id', ['status' => 'Approved', 'id' => $id]);

     return redirect('/');
    }

    public function reject(Request $request, $id)
    {
     DB::update('update mides_vendors set status = :status where id = :id', ['status' => 'Rejected', 'id' => $id]);

     return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```html
Route::prefix('/panel')->group(function () {
 Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
  return view('panel.dashboard');
 });
  /* These routes only display the information/modal
 Route::get('/approve-vendor', 'VendorController@showNewRegistration'); // return vendor.blade.php
 Route::get('/vendor-approved', 'VendorController@showApproved'); // return vendor-approve.blade.php
 Route::get('/vendor-reject', 'VendorController@showRejected'); // return vendor-reject.blade.php
  /* These route used to perform the specific action */
 Route::put('/approve/{id}', 'ApproveVendorController@approve')->name('approve');
 Route::put('/reject{id}', 'ApproveVendorController@reject')->name('reject');
});
```

However, it returns this error.

[Error got after clicking Accept or Reject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/248Mr.jpg)

How do I pass the id of data? I tried as shown in [pass the database value to modal popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827189/pass-the-database-value-to-modal-popup) to create the modal using second answer option (besides the ajax ones). Do I need to create another controller for these?

Edited: after do as explained by @Wreigh, it works, means that the status changed from 'pending' to 'accept/reject'. But, when I return to the previous page, which is the `/panel/approve-vendor` (the page is used for showing the pending list modal) then I got the error `undefined variable vendorId`.

Comment: It because you don't send {id} method to route:Route::put('/approve/{id}'
is that ok to write with post method ?

Comment: Supun Fiction Praneeth, I'm already added the {id} as in ApprovedVendorController, or it is wrong? I see that post and put just give the same result.

Comment: Yes it is wrong, you cannot get id like that when use post or put, i'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the `id` via the url, or you can also use post values. However, let's try via the url as a parameter.

Update your routes to be like these:

```
Route::put('/approve/{id}', 'ApproveVendorController@approve')->name('approve');
Route::put('/reject/{id}', 'ApproveVendorController@reject')->name('reject');
```

Then in your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('approve', $vendorId) }}">
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('reject', $vendorId) }}">
```

If you want via post values.

There's no need to update your routes, but update your controller action signatures:

```
public function approve(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->input('id');
}
public function reject(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->input('id');
}
```

And then insert this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $vendorId }}">
```

**WHY DO YOU ENCOUNTER THE ERROR?**

In your function signature, you are expecting an `$id` parameter, which in your route definition, you do not have. Laravel cannot provide it magically like that, you have to provide it via the url, as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but still got error. The route to view the pending page is Route::get('/approve-vendor', 'VendorController@showNewRegistration'); whereas the two routes with PUT method is used to do the specified action only.

Comment: that problem you've just stated is not stated in your question, maybe it belongs to another question or update your question. Correct me if I'm wrong as the attached images are blocked by my proxy (which I cannot control)

Comment: My bad.. I've edited my questions. Seems the router parameter is expecting the url with id.. I tried to view the /approve-vendor , but since there's no entries left the page cannot be returned.

Answer (score 0):

since your `approve` route is like this `/approve/{id}` you cannot go to `panel/approve` because your are not passing the id

so try this:

**vendor.blade.php** (remove put and your id as hidden input)

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <span class="pull-left">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('approve') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $id}}">
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Approve</button>
     </form>
  </span>
  <span class="pull-right">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('reject') }}">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $id}}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Reject</button>
    </form>
  </span>
</div>
```

**ApprovedVendorController.php** (remove all the parameters)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Vendor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ApproveVendorController extends Controller
{
    public function approve()
    { 
        $id = request('id');

        DB::insert('insert into mides_users(name, email, password) select name,roc_no,password from mides_vendors where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);
        DB::update('update mides_vendors set status = :status where id = :id', ['status' => 'Approved', 'id' => $id]);

        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function reject()
    {
        $id = request('id');
        DB::update('update mides_vendors set status = :status where id = :id', ['status' => 'Rejected', 'id' => $id]);

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php** (remove parameters)

```
Route::prefix('/panel')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('panel.dashboard');
    });
  /* These routes only display the information/modal
    Route::get('/approve-vendor', 'VendorController@showNewRegistration'); // return vendor.blade.php
    Route::get('/vendor-approved', 'VendorController@showApproved'); // return vendor-approve.blade.php
    Route::get('/vendor-reject', 'VendorController@showRejected'); // return vendor-reject.blade.php
  /* These route used to perform the specific action */
    Route::put('/approve', 'ApproveVendorController@approve')->name('approve');
    Route::put('/reject', 'ApproveVendorController@reject')->name('reject');
});
```